# How to find exact match in a column faster without indexing being an option due to non unique values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database column with titles of documents. These titles are not unique, and can be anywhere from a few words to a a few dozen words. I have over 3 million rows. I am trying to optimize looking for exact matches.

Indexing is not possible since there is no primary key, and the column is not unique. I have thought about a binary search, but that's done automatically I've heard when you index something. How can I implement a binary search on a column that's not index-able due to it not being unique?

```
SELECT * FROM cases where title = "Bondelmonte v Bondelmonte"
```

Takes a few seconds, I want it to take a fraction of that time.

Comment: Indexes don't have to be unique. See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html)

Comment: Wow. That just solves it.

Comment: If only they were all that easy. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming MySQL

```
CREATE INDEX title_index ON cases (title)
```

Creates a non-unique index on table "cases" column "title"

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html

You would need to specify UNIQUE to create a unique index

Additionally you may want to create a full text index

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX title_flt_Index ON cases ( title );
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html